# How does "Limit Authentication Session" work in keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak to secure my application. I have a request to limit the number of sessions per user, then I found this and tried it https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/server_admin/topics/threat/auth-sessions-limit.adoc

I have a user called "rxnlab", and I set the authSessionsLimit to 3. What I expect is that I can **only** make 3 sessions with this user, but the truth is the sessions are unlimited, I can make as many connections as I want. The following screenshot shows that there are 10 active sessions, 5 of them are rxnlab (the first page shows 3)
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct config to limit the session per user?
2. If not, what does this config do?

Answer (score 1):

It says here, that whenever you open the login page, it starts a new authentications session, it does not mean, that a user has got access.

This allows you, don't spend memory on countless sessions.

All sessions depend on specific clients, you can manage session time and other things for users.

Keep in mind, that time of living session could be managed per the realm